# Spacing between (multicharacter) math symbols that are in upright font

Tags: math-mode, spacing, formatting

In environmental science (and probably also other disciplines), it is a fairly common practice to use multi-character symbols for variables (often these may be descriptive acronyms of what the variable is).  For example, carbon use efficiency might be given the symbol CUE.

Multi-character symbols are typically typeset using an upright font rather than italics. For example, $\mathrm{FOO}$. Unfortunately this (possibly frowned upon by purists) practice plays havoc with the spacing in math mode. This is particularly evident when two upright symbols are multiplied together.

An example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
This has no spacing: $x = \mathrm{FOO} \mathrm{BAR}$

This has too much spacing: $x = \mathrm{FOO} \quad \mathrm{BAR}$
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

What is the best practice for typesetting multi-character symbols in math to avoid this issue?

Note that using math italics does not help (even if it were corresct to do so) as this introduces space between each character as though they were each separate variables.

Comment: do you really often juxtapose two multi-letter identifiers with no intervening operator? (there is no need to use a massive space like `\quad` of course `\,` would be more suitable, but I am surprised it often occurs. (In my field I almost always use `\mathrm` for variable names but don't think I have ever had two together)

Comment: See [this](https://texblog.org/2014/04/09/whitespace-in-math-mode/) for some options.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - maybe not often. I've managed to avoid this problem up to now. But I am facing this issue now.

Comment: `\,` it is then:-)

Comment: I find `FOO<thin space>BAR` ambiguous anyway, better using an explicit multiplication sign.

Comment: @egreg certainly if it is multiplication, but perhaps the OP's real case is more  `\log\log x` (at least, I hope it is)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: The OP explicitly speaks of “two upright symbols … multiplied together”, so I’d say it’s *not* the `\log\log x` case.

Comment: @GuM never believe what an OP says:-)

Comment: The instance I was concerned with today was indeed multiplication. But general advice on spacing upright symbols correctly would also be valuable to have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Depending on the real use case a math class such as `\mathop` used here may result in correct spacing being applied automatically.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator\FOO{FOO}
\DeclareMathOperator\BAR{BAR}
\begin{document}
This has no spacing: $x = \mathrm{FOO} \mathrm{BAR}$

This some spacing: $x = \mathrm{FOO} \,\mathrm{BAR}$


This automatic spacing: $x = \FOO\BAR$
\end{document}
```